# Subscriptions seem to stop working after a app goes into idle state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

After minimizing the app and putting it into background mode for roughly 5 minutes the subscriptions seem to stop working. I have tried polling and that seems to fix the issue but this doesn't resolve the actual issue with the subscriptions.

I have tried the useSubscription hook first and recently tried useQuery with subscribeToMore. Both seem to have the same issue. I have also tried increasing timeout and inactivityTimeout to be larger than the 5 minutes. It doesn't seem to be the WebSocket disconnecting or anything as we have logs of the WebSocket connection status and it seems to stay connected.

He is an example of how I have the Websocket Client setup.

```
  !isServer
    ? new SubscriptionClient(
        `wss://localhost/graphql`,
        {
          reconnect: true,
          lazy: true,
          timeout: 300000,
          inactivityTimeout: 300000,
          connectionCallback: (error) => {
            if (error) {
              console.error('WS CONNECTION_CB ERROR::: ', error)
            }
            ack = true
            return ack
          }
        }
      )
    : null
) as SubscriptionClient
```

I am using `subscriptions-transport-ws` instead or `graphql-ws` because our provider doesn't work with `graphql-ws` as of yet.

Not sure if someone else has had this issue.